# Python - Matching all elements in a nested list for specific pattern

Tags: python

I am writing a basic script that reads data from a CSV then reformats it and outputs to another CSV. I am reading the CSV file into a nested list of strings.

A short example, would be a CSV with "name", "email", "city".
Read into a nested list as this:

```py
l = [["bob", "bob@email.com", ""], 
     ["Sarah", "", "Madrid"], 
     ["bob", "", "Paris"], 
     ["sarah", "", "Madrid"]]
```

In my script, I am using an if statement to match a pattern in each nested list as such:

```py
for sublist in l:
    if sublist[0] == "bob" and sublist[1] != "" and sublist[2] == "":
        print("Pattern 1")
    elif sublist[0] == "bob" and sublist[1] == "" and sublist[2] != "":
        print("Pattern 2")
    elif sublist[0] == "Sarah" and sublist[1] == "" and sublist[2] != "":
        print("Pattern 3")
    else
        print("Pattern 4")
```

That all works as expected. But, the CSV I am actually working with contains many more values per row, so in my actual script the nested list contains many more elements. As a result, my if statements looks like a massive mess.

I am wondering is there a better way of matching the pattern than using massive if statements?

Comment: What is the pattern that you are trying to match?

Comment: For example, Pattern 1 =  ["bob", value not empty, value is empty] Pattern 2 = ["bob", value is empty, value is not empty] Pattern 3 = ["Sarah", value is empty, value is not empty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Since Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching), there is a new feature exactly for that - [Structural Pattern Matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/). It has many features that you can explore. An example to your case using [multiple patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#matching-multiple-patterns), [specific values](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#matching-specific-values) and [guards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns):

```py
for sublist in l:
    match sublist:
        case ["bob", mail, ""] if mail:
            print("Pattern 1")
        case ["bob", "", city] if city:
            print("Pattern 2")
        case ["Sarah", "", city] if city:
            print("Pattern 3")
        case _:
            print("Pattern 4")
```

Comment: To confirm, I was able to apply your suggestion to my code successfully. Thanks.

Comment: @SgtBob Happy to hear! As I mentioned in the answer itself, do take some time to go over the PEP I linked and learn about the different features and caveats. It would serve you well :) For example if you have more columns that you need to check, you can do something like `case ["bob", mail, "", *cols]`